# How to calculate the variance of regression prediction bias

Tags: linear-regression

In linear regression, if we know $MSE$, which is $MSE=\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^{n}(\hat{y_i}-y_i)^2$, can we know $Var(|\hat{y_i}-y_i|)$? The reason I am trying to find the variance of the bias is that I want to know the error level for the individual point. I was trying to find an upper bound for $|\hat{y_i}-y_i|$, which is $|\hat{y_i}-y_i| \leq \sum_{i=1}^{n}(|\hat{y_i}-y_i|)\leq \sqrt{n}\sqrt{\sum_{i=1}^{n}|\hat{y_i}-y_i|^2}=n\sqrt{MSE}$. But I don't like this result because the upper bound for $|\hat{y_i}-y_i|$ depends on $n$, the more points, the higher the upper bound. Instead, if we can get $Var(|\hat{y_i}-y_i|)$, in addition to $E(|\hat{y_i}-y_i|)\leq \sqrt{MSE}$, then we can use $E+\sigma$, $E+2\sigma$, $E+3\sigma$ to show the error level of $|\hat{y_i}-y_i|$. So how to calculate $Var(|\hat{y_i}-y_i|)$ ?

Thank you!

PS: I tried to calculate it using the definition, but didn't seems to reach an solution:

$Var(|\hat{y_i}-y_i|) \\
= E[(\hat{y_i}-y_i)^2] -E^2[(\hat{y_i}-y_i)] \\
=\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^{n}(\hat{y_i}-y_i)^2-E^2[(\hat{y_i}-y_i)] \\
=MSE-E^2[(\hat{y_i}-y_i)]$

Comment: If you want prediction intervals as a curve both above and below the line, here is [the formula](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/85560/shape-of-confidence-interval-for-predicted-values-in-linear-regression)

Comment: Usually the [formula with t-statistic](http://www2.stat.duke.edu/~tjl13/s101/slides/unit6lec3H.pdf) is used (p.11).

Comment: In arbitrary non-linear regression confidence intervals are calculated using Monte-Carlo simulation.

Comment: At the moment I can't understand what is the difference between from usual decomposition of MSE aka bias-variance trade-off described in every book on regression. The estimation of the variance based on observations and regression model - see, for example, [Bishop - Pattern Recognition and Machine Learning](http://users.isr.ist.utl.pt/~wurmd/Livros/school/Bishop%20-%20Pattern%20Recognition%20And%20Machine%20Learning%20-%20Springer%20%202006.pdf), p.169 and p.171 in pdf (3.47).

Comment: $$MSE = E[(\hat{\beta}^Tx - \beta^Tx)^2] = E[(\hat{\beta}x)^2 ] -2E[\hat{\beta}x] \beta x + (\beta x)^2 = ... \pm (E[\hat{\beta}x])^2 = (E[(\hat{\beta}x)^2 ] -(E[\hat{\beta}x])^2) + (E[(\hat{\beta}x) ] - \beta x)^2$$.  The first is squared bias, the second is variance.